# Android Places Autocomplete widget: api usage not clear

Tags: android, google-places-api, google-places, google-places-autocomplete

today i started integrating the Places Autocomplete widget in my app, with the help of the Autocomplete.IntentBuilder, to give my users the ability to search for an address they want, and get LatLng of it. I followed the descriptions here listed https://developers.google.com/places/android-sdk/autocomplete#add_an_autocomplete_widget

Everything works good, but I am a little bit confused about the api usage limits and pricing.

Are those limits per client/user or by api key? This is not mentioned at https://developers.google.com/maps/billing/understanding-cost-of-use#places-product, or at least I couldn't find anyhting about it. And they talk about "Autocomplete sessions", are this automatically handled by the Autocomplete Intent called?

Thank you!

Comment: The usage limits are per api key

Comment: Have you find an answer to how much we will be paying if we use the AutoComplete Intent?

Answer (score 0):

Usage for google maps apis are associated with an api key.

As of now (april 2019) The first $200 of usage per month are free per api key.

The pricing for autocomplete is per session, a session is the full process of Auto Completing a text field for one location.

The pricing is as follows:

0 - 100,000 requests - $2.83 per 1000 session

100,001 - 500,000 requests - $2.27 per 1000 sessions

500,000 + - contact google

Comment: Do you mean that for using the Autocomplete Intent  I will have to pay 200$ per month?

Comment: no, what I mean is that the first 200 dollars that you spend on the api are free every month